# Regex Match everything except words of particular flag format

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that can match everything else except the random flags..

All flags have this format, starts with `FLAG` and ends in `;`

`FLAG:random_token;`

Example:

```
hello
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
FLAG:xyz6767abcd45xyz; and lorem
lorem ipsum dolor
FLAG:abc123; and hello there,..
hello there....
```

output Im trying to obtain:

```
hello
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 and lorem
lorem ipsum dolor
 and hello there,..
hello there....
```

So far I've tried:
`^(?!FLAG:(.*?);).*`
and
`(?!.*\bFLAG:.*$)^.*$`

But it fails to extract the strings after the semicolon in FLAG:random_token;
Any help would be appreciated

And I've tried deleting all Flags from the block, but I needed the token values later and Also thought regex would be the best fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to remove the flags from the input string, using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a regex to match the `FLAG:` and random token (everything to the next `;`), you can then use a callback function to store the tokens as they are found:

```js
str = `hello
hello world
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
FLAG:xyz6767abcd45xyz; and lorem
lorem ipsum dolor
FLAG:abc123; and hello there,..
hello there....`;

const tokens = [];
str = str.replace(/FLAG:([^;]+);/g, (_, p1) => {
  tokens.push(p1);
  return '';
});
console.log(str);
console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I've taken that approach earlier.. but I needed the token values later in code block, further i didn't wanna allocate another dummy variable for original string, thought regex would simplify it, thanks anyway. and I think, I should clarify this matter in the question

Comment: I'm Accepting your answer, this gets the job done.. and thank you!